# How to call Dictionary method in ios using self

Tags: objective-c

how to call this method in some other method using [self]:

```
-(void)SetValuesInUserInterface:(NSDictionary *)Dic
```

I trid [self SetValuesInUserInterface:) but this doesn't work

Comment: Just an fyi, you might want to update your methods to use camel case for the signature and parameters, most Objective-C code tends to follow that standard:
`- (void)setValuesInUserInterface:(NSDictionary *)dic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(SetValuesInUserInterface:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

Comment: I really hope this is not the way you call your methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
 [self SetValuesInUserInterface:dict];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your Method like this :

```
[self SetValuesInUserInterface:YOURDICTIONARY];
```